# Will "Preparing to finish" be executed after await completes or before?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to C# (coming from a Java background) and I am confused by [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/).

The following example is taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async#example):

```
public async Task<int> ExampleMethodAsync()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    int exampleInt = (await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com")).Length;
    ResultsTextBox.Text += "Preparing to finish ExampleMethodAsync.\n";
    // After the following return statement, any method that's awaiting
    // ExampleMethodAsync (in this case, StartButton_Click) can get the
    // integer result.
    return exampleInt;
}
```

I want to know if the line `ResultsTextBox.Text += "Preparing to finish ExampleMethodAsync.\n";` will execute only after the `await httpClient.GetStringAsync` above it has finished?

My intuition says **it will**, but I am confused as the statement "Preparing to finish", seems like "waiting to finish for the await" and **should be printed before**.

Comment: You can simply try it and see it is called after the previous line is finished.

Comment: How do you think you could get exampleInt without the call beeing finished?

Comment: There is some syntactic sugar here. When the code is compiled, your async method is split-up into a statemachine. The method is cut in mutiple parts. The code after the await is run when the task (which is returned from the `GetStringAsync()` is complete.

Answer (score 3):

In c#, when you use async and await, translate the await as a pause button. it tells your method "wait until the task done and then continue". in your code, (where you have await), the method is waiting for httpClient.GetStringAsync to finish grabbing data.

and next line ResultsTextBox.Text, will run after the upper line task complete.in simple words, this line will run only after GetStringAsync is done, not before.

So your guess is true and will run after the await call is complete.

Answer (score 1):

"Preparing to finish" will be executed after the `await` completes. Here's a [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EVDt5p) where the code inside an awaited async function is executed before the "Preparing to finish" line.

The result:

```
Length of response body: 40774
Preparing to finish ExampleMethodAsync.
```

I also thought the article you linked above had a helpful analogy:

```
static async Task<Toast> MakeToastWithButterAndJamAsync(int number)
{
    var toast = await ToastBreadAsync(number);
    ApplyButter(toast);
    ApplyJam(toast);

    return toast;
}
```

The toast has to be ready before spreading butter and jam on it. :)

Demo code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static async Task<int> ExampleMethodAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        int exampleInt = await GetResponseBodyLength("http://msdn.microsoft.com", httpClient);

        // This will run only after GetResponseBodyLength() has finished
        Console.WriteLine("Preparing to finish ExampleMethodAsync.\n");

        // After the following return statement, any method that's awaiting
        // ExampleMethodAsync (in this case, StartButton_Click) can get the
        // integer result.
        return exampleInt;
    }

    public static async Task<int> GetResponseBodyLength(string requestUri, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        var responseBodyLength = (await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUri)).Length;

        Console.WriteLine($"Length of response body: {responseBodyLength}");

        return responseBodyLength;
    }
    
    static async Task<int> Main()
    {
        return await ExampleMethodAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The C# compiler will move your method to a new class, wrap you code with a `switch` statement, similar to [duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). Then replace each `await` with a block of code that will save the state and register a continuation callback. And insert a `case` label to resume the method. Each `return` is replaced with `.SetResult()` which will execute each continuation in series.

The first time your method `awaits` an incomplete task, your method will also return an incomplete task to its caller. Allowing the calling thread to resume immediately.

When asynchronous IO completes, the runtime will obtain a thread from the thread pool to resume execution. When any other type of task completes, all continuations will be executed in series on that same thread. This means that after the `async` method resumes, the call stack will be inverted, revealing the chain of `.SetResult` calls that lead to your continuation being resumed.

For win32 UI code, where any change to the UI must occur on the main thread. The default behaviour of `await` is to resume execution on the main thread, which can be overridden by calling `await [task].ConfigureAwait(false)`.

If you want to see what that looks like, lets simplify your example a bit then use a [decompiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5nJQDM6AhgEYDOALgE6kDG1mM6AwugN7Lq/oAOtAPbUApk1HAyVOo2ZQAbAB4AlgDtqAPnQBxUdQAyotQHNqACwAUASnxI+A4WIlSKNek0wAWdAHk1bEIAtvwANvqiNnYOPHzEmAAcmMrqWugAogAepCHhALL65kLAAIKUAJ5qDDaxvNz2Dnyp6KLZuaIAkhroALyYAJy6+kamFlG1jf6B7WLjDY2YAOwtbWGdGtF8AL7IW0A===).

```cs
public abstract class C {
    protected abstract Task<int> GetLength();
    protected abstract void OnComplete();
    
    public async Task<int> ExampleMethodAsync()
    {
        int exampleInt = await GetLength();
        OnComplete();
        return exampleInt;
    }
}
```